# Как в заданной области в яндекс картах, Автоматически создавать метки по категориям?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На сайте, необходимо добавлять метки с собственными категориями:

- кафе
- театр
- клиника
- детский сад

Сделали все это вручную, внесли много адресов, все работает.

Вопрос: не хочется каждый раз вручную добавлять новые объекты в категории: кафе, театры, клиники и пр.

Есть ли у я.карт готовые категории и метки по этим категориям? Как ими пользоваться, чтобы в определенной области на карте можно было выводить готовые метки из готовых категорий? Я поискал в API, либо я не вижу в упор, либо я не знаю как правильно это называется.

Comment: Первое что приходит на ум описано в песочнице 
 Яндекса: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo Организовать поиск категории можно так же. При этом можно скрыть попап поисковой строки noPopup: true , а можно вообще убрать её за карту. Содержимое же строки можно изменять заранее заготовленными кнопками с категориями, в интерфейсе карты или вообще за её пределами. Ограничить зону поиска помогут boundedBy useMapBounds и strictBounds по желанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В API Карт есть [HTTP API Геопоиска](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/?from=SO) - специальный API, который ищет организации с учётом заданных параметров.

В вашем случае потребуется делать по запросу на категорию. Например, вот так:

```
https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=аптека&bbox=<координаты области вокруг нужного вам адреса>&lang=ru_RU&apikey=<API-ключ>
```

Результаты нужно вывести на карту как метки, можно при желании отфильтровать лишние по дальности и дополнительно собрать в какой-то свой список.

Comment: здравствуйте! спасибо большое!